# How Can i get values from two result records into one line

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

am trying to work on a  taxi meter mobile app  for android ,i have two tables  : Client and Point  ,Client_Point_Depart and Client_Point_Destination are foreign keys coming from table point(Point_ID) , I’v been trying to find a query to get me for each  client the ID the X,Y of the Point of type Depart and the X,Y of the point of type Destination ,Distance,Time.
[image]
Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select dbo.Client.ClientID, pd1.PointX, pd1.PointY, pd2.PointX, pd2.PointY
from Client
join dbo.Point pd1 ON pd1.PointID = dbo.Client.ClientPointDepart
join dbo.Point pd2 ON pd2.PointID = dbo.Client.ClientPointDest
```